# error in rpmbuild for MeeGo

Tags: rpmbuild, meego

I am getting error when I am trying to do rpmbuild to build the kernel from source for MeeGo 1.2.

After run this command:

```
rpmbuild -bp --target $(uname -m) kernel-adaptation-intel-automative.spec
```

I am getting this error:

```
make ARCH=x86 listnewconfig
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.G80JZf
```

Comment: Please reply someone what can be the solution this type of problem in Meego

Comment: "Bad exit status" just means it failed, with a temporary filename. How about pasting the whole dump?

Comment: Sorry, I have found the problem's reason and the solution. gcc was not installed.After installing gcc, rpmbuild works fine.